# How to remove Panda Cloud from Context Menu?

Tags: windows-7, context-menu

Unfortunately there is no option in Panda Cloud 3.0.1 to disable the context menu entry `Scan with Panda Cloud Antivirus`.

I tried to remove it by using [ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/) but the software does not list Panda Cloud. I also tried other tools to edit the context menu but they did not show the entry.

Can anybody point me to the entry in the Registry Editor where it can be disabled?

--

**Why I need this:**

I am doing screenrecordings. When I right mouseclick a file, I need to show a clean context menu. As it is on every computer. Of course, I could just uninstall Panda Cloud, but I like the software as my computer is not slowing down.

Here is a video example from http://www.speedflips.com/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=E-nNjnK11Bk#t=15

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer from Panda TechSupport:

> You can check thekeys to be deleted with Autoruns from SysInternals in the Explorer tab
>
> There are some registry keys to be removed (export them before deleting) from safe mode:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\UAContextMenu
>       HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\UAContextMenu

Only thing I still need is a .reg file for Windows to enable or disable the context menu entry. If you know how the file has to look like, please post your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying [ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) and [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html). They both work fairly well at removing programs from the context menu.

[image: ShellMenuView]
[image: ShellExView]